# How do I update today widget from container app?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, today-extension

I'm looking for a way to update the today widget whenever it's activated/ viewed. I will get data from a web API, all the infrastructure code lies in the shared project, so I need to use it instead of duplicating code in the widget project. 
I'm setting the widget in the AppDelegate class:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            LoadExtension();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        private void LoadExtension()
        {
            var controller = NCWidgetController.GetWidgetController();
            controller.SetHasContent(true, "com.companyname.Textension");
        }
```

I looked for an event in `controller` but it doesn't define any event.
I was looking for something like this:

```
        private void LoadExtension()
        {
            var controller = NCWidgetController.GetWidgetController();
            controller.SetHasContent(true, "com.companyname.Textension");
            controller.Activated += UpdateWidget();
        }

        public void UpdateWidget()
        {
            //update widget here
        }
```

Comment: They are in completely difference sandboxed processes, typically you use some type of data (CoreData/UserDefaults/) sharing convention via "App Group" if the widget needs to "push/pull" data from the host app,

Comment: Any tutorial/ documentation on this?

Comment: Apple Dev site has docs and examples, plus there are "lots" tutorials/blogs/etc on the web concerning this exact topic, Google/Bing it